# MSSQL Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

I have an application that almost continuously works with inserting or updating data. Since multiple requests are handled asynchronous I wrote my queries like below. I used an example based on SO, but that's not what I'm actually doing.

```
DECLARE @rows int;
INSERT INTO [user] ([username],[reputation])
SELECT [username],[reputation]
FROM (
    SELECT [username]=:user,[reputation]=:rep
) A
WHERE A.[username] NOT IN (
  SELECT [username]
  FROM [user]
);
SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT;

IF (@rows=0) BEGIN
  UPDATE [user]
  SET [reputation]=:rep, [updated]=GetDate()
  WHERE [username]=:user
END;
```

This is passed in total to the database with `PHP` `PDO`. Because of the amount of data and other processing factors it's heavy on the (cheap) VPS it's running on. It's not really a problem if these processes run slow or get delayed, but on the other hand this data should be available via a website and then the queries on the data should be quick.

I was thinking about replicating parts of the processed data to a second server and running the website on that database. But I'm wondering how that would actually work with a query like above.

I'm guessing the `UPDATE` query will only be in the transaction log when `@rows=0`, so that won't be a problem.

But would the first part only send `INSERT INTO [user] ([username],[reputation]) VALUES ('Hugo Delsing', '10k')` or the entire query with the `WHERE NOT IN ()` query?

Most of the time a user would exists, so if it only runs the new inserts that won't be a problem. But if it would run the entire query each time the benefits would be small.

Obviously I could wrap the first part up in another check `if exists(select 1 from [user] where [username] = :user)` to make sure it only runs when there is no user, but I'm wondering if that is necessary.

Also: Would replicating be the way to go or does `MS SQL` offer other/better solutions for something like this?

Comment: For transactional replication only the insert statement with values will be sent and not the query as is.  I did not understand the problem you are trying to solve.  Transaction will only only be replicated once committed in current server.

Answer (score 0):

I wen through your post and here is my response (one-by-one) on the basis of what I got.

`It's not really a problem if these processes run slow or get delayed`

That's good if it suits you requirement.

`But on the other hand this data should be available via a website and then the queries on the data should be quick`

and

`I was thinking about replicating parts of the processed data to a second server and running the website on that database.`

In transactoinal replication SQL server allow to create index on the tables in subscriber database. So you want to use subscriber to generate reports, you can optimize you query and create indexes (on subscriber DB) that boosts your query performance to get quick response.

But if you want to make transaction at both side `INSERT,UPDATE, DELETE` then you should go for **MERGE Replication**.

I didn't understood rest part of you post. It would be good to write proper suggestion if you clarify it.

Thanks!